# How to authenthicate from my application to a SSO of my client

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs3.0

I am developing a web application using EC2 on AWS.

In this application my client is requesting to use his SSO (Single Sign On) so I can verify the user against his Active Directory. My problem is that I can't get to know where to begin with, these are some of my questions:

1) Is this SSO takes place on my code or on my server?

2) Do I have to make different configuration for differents deployment environments (for example aws, azure, digitalocean, etc)?

3) Where do I define, send and parse SAML 2.0 format?

4) Do I have the send a POST request to the server where the SSO is installed? Or how is it managed?

So far I have found this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fmNoqz6Urw), but I am still do not know what to do first, so any step by step information will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First you need the client (Identity Provider IdP) SAML2 metadata. This will have their SSO endpoint URL and their X509 signing certificate.

Then you send them your SAML2 metadata with your Attribute Consumer Service (ACS) URL and X509 signing certificate.

Sample metadata [here](https://wiki.geant.org/display/eduGAIN/Basic+SP+Metadata+Example). Or you can build it [here](https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php).

The certificates are normally long lived self signed certificates. They can be self signed as each side has a copy of the other's certificate which they will use to verify the signed request and response.

You construct a `SAMLRequest` and POST it to their SSO URL. There's an example request [here](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_req.php).

They display their login page to the user and the user authenticates at their end.

They gather attributes for the user from their Active Directory and turn them into SAML attributes and put them in a `SAMLResponse`.

They POST the `SAMLResponse` to your ACS URL. There's an example response [here](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php).

You verify the signature on their `SAMLResponse` using their X509 certificate from their SAML2 metadata.

You extract the SAML Attributes from their verified `SAMLResponse` and take appropriate action in your application, e.g. create the user an account, perhaps their email address is one of their attributes.

The above is called the SAML2 Web Browser SSO Profile, explained [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_saml_web_sso.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your stack, you can use something like:

- Shibboleth (middleware, install on your server, it interrupts requests to specific paths requiring Authn against the Identity Provider [ADFS], and returns the user after successful auth setting some attributes telling you info about the user such as username, etc.). *Works best if you can compartmentalize secured content into a particular path on the site like /secure.*
- SimpleSAMLphp (protect PHP resources directly)
- Commercial SAML (ComponentSpace, etc. - works well if .Net app)

Basically, find something for your stack. **DO NOT TRY TO ROLL YOUR OWN SAML IMPLEMENTATION!**